# code coloring in github README

Tags: github

I use github. My README.md contains code samples. How can I make this code appear in color when viewing my README in the github with a browser? I am willing to use gists but not sure how to integrate them in the README.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can add a language hint like so:

````
```javascript
// Your code here
```
````

Comment: Interestingly ```js ..... is not working

Comment: @RatulHasan: Not working where?

Comment: your solution works fine, just tried to check if writing `js` instead of `javascript` will work or not. On GitHub issue, `js` seems not working as substitution

Comment: @RatulHasan: `js` is supposed to work as an alias on GitHub (including issues), though. Might have been a temporary bug?

Comment: Maybe... I am on mobile, so device limitations maybe 

Answer (score 6):

Begin & end the block with
```
like this

````
```
// your code block here
```
````

Optionally, you can add the language identifier like 'ruby' after the first ``` like this

````
```<language identifier>
//  your code block here
```
````